# Auto-layout view xib - no editable constraints? I need centered elements

Tags: ios, uiview, xib, autolayout

I have a view that I've built via xib, and I call setFrame to size it in different ways.

The view has labels and buttons, but they should remained centered vertically despite size change.

In IB, I don't see any constraints on the view, labels, or buttons that are editable.

How can I create a view with a xib and specify auto-layout constraints to let vertical centering happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click and drag from labels and buttons to the view.